# Change .mlmodel auto-generated file forever

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, app-store, coreml

In my objective-c project, I use Core ML model for image recognition which generates objective-c .h/.m files for interaction with it.

The problem is that this files contains syntax errors and is not compiled. I can fix them by myself and it will work if I run the app on simulator or device, but I can't create **archive** for AppStore, because during archiving the file with errors is created anew and build fails.

So could you tell how can I solve this problem?

PS: I took mlmodel from [here](https://github.com/hetelek/GuessMyDrawing-ios)

Error after archiving the project:
[image]
The problem is that the name of the method misses underscores ("_").
It may be fixed by renaming method like this:

```
- (instancetype)initWithCategory_softmax_scores:(NSDictionary<NSString *, NSNumber *> *)category_softmax_scores category:(NSString *)category;
```

Comment: Could you please post your error when you archive your project?

Comment: @QuocNguyen updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve solved this problem by creating new class with the code from files (.h & .m), which generates mlmodel. In this file I fixed all errors. Next I’ve just imported my new file instead of previous (generated) and project has successfully archived.

Comment: Additionally I set the language on which the model’s class will be generated to Swift